# how to build and run the samples in opencvsharp?

Tags: c#, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I download the opencvsharp by nuget and it can be use actually.However,I don't know how to run the sample it gives.There are just some file with .cs suffix and a file named samplebase.csproj.Are there something i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Cs files are c# source files. The csproj is a c# project created with Visual Studio.  Just open the project in Visual Studio, compile and run it.

Comment: @Sleeve-fishkiller I haven't downloaded the code, but there should be a README file or documentation in the web site with those details.